# Is it good practice to substitute a resistor by parallel and series-ing them?

Tags: resistors, analog

In our electronics (I) lab they told us to never use resistors in parallel or series and choose a value near your calculations. but never explained why.
Is it ok to just buy the range of 1ohm to 1M and use them to get the resistance I want?

I'm starting to build a guitar amplifier. while buying the parts I may end up with lots of spares.

thanks

Comment: Pragmatically everyone does it if they don't have the right value on hand to accomplish a day's goal (even with surface mount...) but buying a good assortment is worthwhile.  This question can't really have a definitive answer.

Comment: you can make 16 different values with 10k,20k,40k,80k in parallel and 16 more in series and having matched resistance is important for input offset, but there are practical limits due to tolerances so if using 1% parts it wont make sense to add 100k + 10k + 20k  + 1k .  spare parts are useful but not as convenient as a kit of values and design using these.

Comment: "they told us to never use resistors in parallel or series and choose a value near your calculations. but never explained why" I would like to hear their reasoning. There are some instances where you have use series resistors when the voltage is too high for a single resistor to handle or safety. So if you need a 1M resistor, but the physical resistor can only tolerate 500V and you are applying 1000V, you use two in 500K series, or four 250K in series. It is also safer if one fails as long as the resistors are not already at their limit while in series. That's not really "substituting" though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The pros about using a single resistor over either parallel or series:

- Less cost
- Less wiring
- Less space needed
- Less error prone (one component less to fail)

The pros about using a combination of resistors:

- You can select resistors from the ones you have if you have a limited number of values
- When putting them parallel, you increase the power (Watts), see remark of greggo
- (You reduce the average tolerance, however since you have to design for worst case situations, this does not help).
- Reducing need of (re)loading reels for high production volume, see remark of Tom Carpenter
- Reducing risk when one component breaks, and in some cases (personal injuries) even mandatory such as in e.g. ESD gear or EX certified gear, see remarks of SteveSh and rackandboneman.

However, in any professional (and serious hobby project), I would use only one resistor when possible, taking the closes/best resistor value and power into account.

Comment: Parallel or series both spread the power (but of course it only spreads evenly if both resistors are the same). I've run into cases where I couldn't get the value or wattage I needed for power resistors at the local electronics supply, and this is a good way to get around that.

Comment: In terms of other pro points - for large quantity assembly it can be cheaper to use parallel or series resistors to make up a different value if it reduces the number of unique components (reel slots on your production line). The cost of placing the extra 0.01p resistor can be less than the time to load another reel.

Comment: One place where parallel resistors have a use is in fault tolerance.  Say you're dividing down a 100 V peak signal for sampling by a 5V input range ADC, and that the ADC will be damaged if anything beyond 5 V is applied to its input.  At first blush, you might decide to used 1:20 voltage divider, say 100 Kohms in series with 4.7 Kohms.  The weakness with this approch is that if the 4.7K resistor opens up for some reason, then the full 100V will be applied to the ADC, destroying it and possibly propagating on to damage other parts.  Using 2 4.7Ks in parallel eliminates this failure mode.

Comment: @greggo good point thanks, I updated my answer (and added your name).

Comment: @TomCarpenter Thanks, I added it to my answer (with your name)

Comment: @SteveSh I added it to my answer too, thanks ... I thought it was not good practice to rely on breaking of a component, except when using a kind of isolated (spare) circuit.

Comment: @SteveSh AFAIK this practice (multiple resistors in series) is recommended or even proscribed in cases where a resistor failing short could get someone hurt (eg ESD gear, EX certified gear)...

Comment: @rackandboneman Thanks for the remark (I added  it to my answer).

Comment: @SteveSh To get 4.7K with two in parallel, you'd need to use 9.4Ks...

Comment: A value of placing resistor in series is to enhance the overall resistance precision. However, that has typically implications when all the resistors have the same value.

Comment: @MarioVernari … are you sure? I mean, the average precision will be better, but in worst case nothing changes (2 times 100 ohm 10% resistors in series will have the same worst case precision as 1 time 200 ohm 10% resistor, e.g. lowest value: 2 * (100 * 0.9) versus 1 * (200 * 0.9) = 180 versus 180). Only the average will be closer to 200.

Comment: @MichelKeijzersI admit to be rusty on electronics (I'm doing mostly programming), but I remember quite well that the overall expected value gets closer than a single resistor. That's because, yes, you can expect a random (roughly gaussian) error around the nominal value, hence the better expectation.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers probably my observation is worth for "old" resistors, than modern chip-on-reel, where the pieces are very similar each other.

Comment: @MarioVernari I fully agree to that (that it's like a gaussian curve) and the average is closer with 2 resistors versus 1. However, if the precision needs to be by design very small, a better precision single resistor should be used anyway, and if the precision is not needed, than also a single resistor can be used.

Comment: @MarioVernari …. related to old resistors (or new ones too), if you have 2 not so precise resistors, and do not happen to have a more precise one, THAN it can be used (after measuring them). Although in theory, if you have enough resistors (even 10% ones), if you measure many of them, probably some will have an exact value. With older (non precise) resistors you might be able to use this trick more often.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers definitely agree! mine was more a teaching observation, rather an "industrial" approach!

Comment: @MarioVernari Yes and it is useful (however, if you don't mind I don't add it to the answer, since most people I guess they use either new(er) resistors, or industrial like (which means: use a precise enough resistor for the calculated design, or use multiple when safety is an issue).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers last answer (the site gets angry): do not add it! I left electronics design around 20 years ago, when chips were used only for large productions. By the way, if I'd build a home single-unit project (like an amplifier or so), I would use discrete components and prototyping boards: I really can't handle chips!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102489/discussion-between-michel-keijzers-and-mario-vernari).

Answer (score 7):

If you are purchasing parts for an amplifier design that you will be tweaking resistor sizes to optimize performance I strongly suggest that you invest in a resistor assortment kit. Such a kit will prove useful for you for many future projects as well. I still regularly use resistors from an 0805 SMT kit that I purchased over 16 years ago.

Kits such as these give you a lot of flexibility to stick with the single resistor philosophy or in selecting unique in between values either by doing components in series or parallel.

You can get kits such as this one with axial leaded resistors:

[image]

<sup>*[Screen Shot Source](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/yageo/RS112/RS112-KIT-ND/19985)*</sup>

Alternatively kits are available with SMT components of a specific physical size. Here is one kit with 0603 sized resistors:

[image]

[image]

<sup>*[Screen Shot Source](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay-Dale/LTW964TPW06030DB00?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsh5%252BMCVlvUQO4i8yksRqU37N%252B6ZaEn9j0%3D)*</sup>

Answer (score 6):

What they *should* have said, was that in practice you work with what you got and it often isn't necessary to use networks just to get a non-standard value. For that, you really want to get used to the E12/24/48/96 series.

For example, if you calculated you need 18800 Ohm, a 18k7 would usually be good enough. Often enough 18k will do fine. Not even talking about tolerances on those values (although the problem of tolerances does add-up if you start combining resistors, make sure you use those that are accurate enough if your application needs it), often enough **simple** is better than **accurate**.

The intent behind their statement was fine, but a bit too absolute. Sometimes, you *do* need a very specific value. However, in that case it could be wiser to put a single E192 resistor in it instead.

For prototyping purposes, having the entire E48 or better available is quite useful. Don't let anyone stop you from getting a range of resistors.

If you don't have a list already, find your E-series lists [here](http://www.resistorguide.com/resistor-values/#E96_series_tolerance_1).

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking combining resistors is either irellevant  or self defeating, but when prototyping one does what one needs to so of course it is done extensively.  For example it is easy to solder an smt resistor on top of another and saves a step vs desoldering if I want to quickly try a value smaller than what I chose .

Consider that resistors values are laderred on a logarithmic scale with steps based on tolerance of the series , however many applications just need to be in the ballpark and even 5% is overkill

For example , e.g. 10/100/1k/10k/100k/1M +/-50%will cover 90% of resistor cases.

For those applications you should just use the closest common value since you don't much care anyway (e.g. all pullups to 10k). So stacking parts isn't needed except if you are simply short some particularly low high or low value

However there are situations where one precisely calculates the resistor value,  combining resistors is self defeating because the errors combine , so better tolerance parts are needed when using esistors in parallel or series, this is both unreliable and more expensive

For example  if you calculate a value such as 105.2k , if the requirement  is +/-10% simply round to 100k 5% part  , if it is +/-1% use the nearest value in that series, if you need finer control, you may choose to combine 0.1% parts at a cost. In the most extreme a trim resistor can be laser trimmed to control impedance during assembly (or a trimpot if it needs regular adjustment). Only you know what the requirement is for that application

There are second order optimizations, especially when considering design for cost , but those are case by case wierdness usually as a result of askew logic of volume production

Answer (score 3):

There is no universal answer on your question.

Normally in low power electronics you try to use available space as efficient as possible by taking in consideration possible interaction of closely located components.

For example in **radio** circuits you would try to shield oscillators from amplifiers, make traces as short as possible to avoid **antenna** effect by picking up electro-magnetic energy in the conductors.

In power electronics very often you have to use series or parallel conducted resistors to dissipate heat (otherwise you are looking into purchase of quite expensive resistors).

As you mention the guitar amplifier (pre-amplifier) then probably you will use opamps. In this case we deal with low current, low voltage circuit and you will end up with a few potentiometers (variable resistor).

Now depending on selected technology (through hole or SMD) you have to select electronic components. SMD is most space/cost efficient but not easy to work with without proper equipment (depending what you have in your *workshop* -- with proper equipment SMD is easy to work with).

If you refer to pre-amplifier then probably it would be sufficient to use 0.125 Watt resistors.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/1280Pcs-64-values-1-ohm-10M-ohm-1-4W-Metal-Film-Resistors-Assortment-Kit-Tool/193219186243

https://www.ebay.com/itm/3120pcs-156-Values-1-4W-1-Metal-Film-Resistors-Assortment-Kit-1-ohm-10M-ohm/112113966131

https://www.ebay.com/itm/2600pcs-130-Values-1-4W-1-0-25W-Metal-Film-Resistors-Resistance-Assortment-Kit/401036186511

If you are referring to guitar power amplifier then for a start you need to define what **power** output is expected. Based on this information you will need to decide on **class** of amplifier based on percent of harmonics (distortion effects create significant percentage of harmonics). You can use *predesined* specialized ICs or go for discrete components.

Specialized ICs significantly simplify the circuit and with good components guaranty stated specification (please pay special attention to quality of capacitors).

At this point you will need to look into power consumption by power amplifier and what complexity it will involve to design power supply. PWM power supplies give most efficient conversion from high to lower voltage -- but known for significant radio emission of radio harmonics (even sufficient shielding not a solution).

Class D amplifiers are among most power efficient amplifiers but will poorly fit for radio electronics (PWM switching *amplification* produces a lot of *radio-noise*) and audiophiles will say 'no-no-no' as switching amplifier introduces a lot of radio interference which will 'leak through' into pre-amplifiers.

Just a few thoughts from the top of the head to take into consideration.